# Entity Framework: How to upgrade or downgrade during migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

this is my migration code AddIsDefault. now tell me how could i down grade later after upgrade and again upgrade later. what command i need to issue at package manager console.

```
public partial class AddIsDefault : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Contacts", "IsDefault", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Contacts", "IsDefault");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can rollback to preious migrations using update-database -TargetMigration <MigrationName> but you cannot just exclude this migration for a while - for this you will have to change your model and create a migration for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't need to downgrade** here.If you don't need `IsDefault` column then `remove` it on the `model` and `run migration` again as shown below.

```
PM> Add-Migration "Remove_IsDefault"

PM> Update-Database
```

Later if you need to add it again,change the model and run it again for the new change.Very simple :)

**Update :**

On Package Manager Console :

```
PM> Update-Database –TargetMigration: YourMigrationScriptName
```

**Reference :** [**Code First Migrations**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: good answer but i am looking for a way to know what command i need to use to upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: sorry do not understand this command `Update-Database –TargetMigration: YourMigrationScriptName ` suppose my migration code exist in cs file whose name is `201609071433440_AddIsDefault.cs` so now tell me what command i should use ?

Comment: this name you have to give there `AddIsDefault`.

Comment: `PM> Update-Database –TargetMigration: AddIsDefault`

Comment: i found one sample like `Update-Database -Target:201607242157114_7` they use -target keyword only but u use –TargetMigration: so which one is right?

Comment: `–TargetMigration` means it will call down menthod ? if use later again this command like `Update-Database TargetMigration: AddIsDefault` then it will call up method again ? please share the knowledge

Comment: please see this section on the above doc `Migrate to a Specific Version (Including Downgrade)` and let me know where do you need any clarification after that.